# Can I use the HAT eeprom pins as a uart?

Tags: uart, hat

I have a Pi 4B and I want to use the HAT EEPROM I2C pins for the uart 4 that is behind them. This is a board just for me and all my other uart locations are in use. How do I disable the EEPROM scan and then configure those pins to be a uart?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 (PiZeroW, Pi4 or later models)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-pizerow-pi4-or-later-models) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107780/8697

Comment: @Milliways No, but maybe I'm doing something wrong ( I see I actually wanted uart2).  So I added this enable_uart=2 force_eeprom_read=0 to my config.txt and rebooted. But no new device appeared like: /dev/AMA1 as described in that link.

Comment: I added dtoverlay=uart2 and a new /dev/ttyAMA1 appeared.  Then I was able to write a byte out and see it on the scope.  I don't know if enable_uart=2 is also needed.

Comment: DO NOT post detail in Comments - edit your Question

Comment: Odd, this worked fine on the Pi4, but not on the Pi 2W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used UART2 in the past. (I was actually trying to use the pins for other purposes - most failed) BUT I did get UART2 working and used it for serial communication as noted in a footnote to
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107780/8697.

This was some time ago - probably running Buster. I can't confirm that it works with current OS but worth experimenting.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!